# Кодировка SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, кодировка

В в одном поле в таблице может быть сразу три языка:

1. Немецкий
2. Нидерландский
3. Французский

Для первых двух языков кодировка `Latin1_General_CI_AS` подходит и все нормально отображается, но если язык французский, то появляются странные символы.

**Таблица:**

```
[Language] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL
```

**Входные данные:**

```
FR,Activités TVA
NL,BTW-activiteiten
```

**В таблице:**

```
FR,ActivitÃ©s TVA
NL,BTW-activiteiten
```

Как это можно исправить? Возможно ли использовать несколько кодировок для одной строки?

Comment: *В одной строке в таблице может быть сразу три языка:* В одном поле или в трёх разных? *Возможно ли использовать несколько кодировок для одной строки?* `COLLATION` может указываться для каждого поля отдельно. Но не для отдельных записей.

Comment: Исправил вопрос. В одном поле может быть три разных языка.

Comment: Думаю помогло бы добавить в вопрос примеры строк что должно быть и что в БД.  На Unicode (nvarchar к примеру) переходить не пробовали?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko добавил пример

Comment: "в одном поле в таблице может быть сразу три языка" --- nchar/nvarchar - однозначно! И не забывайте обрамлять юникодные строки юникодными кавычками: N'Activités', например

Comment: @mega, я использую nvarchar, а как быть с юникодными кавычками, не знаю. Дело в том, что данные загружаются из csv файла при помощи bulk insert

Comment: @Nikita, а CSV у вас сохранен в UTF-8 Code Page ?

Comment: @MaxU, да, в UTF-8

Comment: @Nikita, я думая в вопросе стоит привести код, который используется для загрузки данных

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5498033/5741205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновление `SQL Server` не помогло. Пробовал разные варианты, со сменой кодировки и указание `CODEPAGE` в `SQL` запросе. Ничего не помогло.

Удалось решить проблему изменение кодировки `.csv` файла. С `UTF-8` на `Windows 1252`. Размер файла не меняется и в БД нормально отображается текст.

Answer (score 1):

В версии **SQL Server 2014 SP2** реализована поддержка **UTF-8**:

> - Для утилиты BCP и команды SQL-BULK INSERT Transact добавлена    поддержка импорта UTF-8.
> - Добавлена поддержка UTF-8 экспорта для утилиты BCP.

Таким образом, можно воспользоваться следующим примером:

```
BULK INSERT table_name
FROM 'drive:path\file_name'
WITH (CODEPAGE = '65001', DATAFILETYPE = 'Char')
```

Более подробно об обновлении: [UTF-8 encoding support in SQL Server 2014 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq)

Comment: Установил SQL Server 2017, пробовал код, который вы написали, но проблема осталась

Comment: @Nikita мне удавалось найти информацию о поддержке в SQL 2016 и SQL 2014 SP2, про 2017 речи не идет.